# What would be the true negative in this scenario

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have just written a program to calculate the number of apples in a basket.
I am then calculating the metrics for the classification of the performance.
I am not sure how to  classify  what a True negative is.

Comment: I'm not sure true negative has any meaning in this case. The difference between the true number of apples and the detected number sounds more interesting.

Comment: @GilLevi I was able to solve the True positive and false positive. I just need to understand True negative to be able to calculate specificity.

Comment: true negative: your program says it is NOT AN APPLE, where it is indeed NOT AN APPLE.

false negative: your program says it is NOT AN APPLE, where it is actually AN APPLE.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here has a name, which is [confusion table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). Since your problem is a classification problem, it seems quite obvious that in your case a true negative will be your algorithm correctly classifying a detected object as "not an apple". Therefore, you'll need a dataset to construct your confusion table. I gather from what you wrote that you already have one.

Does this answer the question ?